# Why Casteism is there in Hinduism?

Tags: krishna, caste-system

If we the people are the actual reason for building our own castes then why do gods (krishna as kshatriya, parasurama as brahmana) take birth in particular castes?

Comment: Are you asking why Krishna took birth based on caste or why Castism is there in Hinduism? Question is unclear = please edit your question to a particular topic. Or else moderators would close the question as "unclear"

Comment: Why Parshurama took birth as brahmana? To get the answer you should know the purpose of Parshurama avatar of Vishnu. For that you need to read Parshurama story. I suggest you to watch "vishnu puraan" series on youtube. There you will get your answer. This is old series that's why its trusworthy coz earlier series used to be made on scriptures, not on books. Today's series are interpolated. SO watching old series would be best. Let me tell you its beautiful series.

Comment: @akshaykumars Its related, not duplicate. Actually, only half question is duplicate, not full. He also asked that "why Gods did take birth in particular caste" which is unique part and your mentioned post is not questioning/answering that part of this post :)

Comment: kshatriya, brahmana are called professions on the previous yugas like now we have teachers, engineers, doctors, etc., Krishna is the avatar of Lord Narayana, so in this world everyone has profession. Krishna came to this word to fight in a war, so he had chosen his profession. And what fault do you find? P.S one profession is not inferior to other.